# Headless and UI Plugin Development for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, headless-rcp

I want to make a Headless Console plugin and a UI plugin for Eclipse.
Requirments are like this;

- Headless plugin will be accessed from cmd
- Headless plugin will accept couple of parameters
- UI plugin will show windows to user to input these parameters
- UI plugin will trigger headless plugin with the parameters provided by user.

Headless plugin processes some resources when triggered. So calling only a method of headless plugin does not work for me. I have to have the bundle instance in the plugin to access the resources.

I need an approach on how to achieve starting a headless plugin from UI plugin.
Headless plugin cont

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand what the problem with calling a method is. The plugin will be automatically started when you do this.

Comment: I was not able to work with that but maybe it is my mistake I will try again

Comment: Sounds like what you call "Headless plugin" is simply an external application. Must it be a plugin?

Comment: Actually tried it again it worked. I guess i did something else wrong. Just calling any class from plugin automatically creates the bundle as well. Yeah it has to be a plugin because it creates a custom eclipse project and builds it. Ui part responsible for giving the options to user. So user will be able to create a project from console and from create project routine of eclipse. Thanks greg-449